# How to use mask for Mayavi's grid plots?

Tags: python, 3d, plot, enthought, mayavi

I'm using python and mayavi2 for 3D plotting.  I'm plotting a sphere using the mesh command, and now I want to color some of the panels of the sphere a different color.  It seems like this is what the mask option is for, but I can't get it to work (I just get the whole sphere recolored).

http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.mesh
"mask:  boolean mask array to suppress some data points"

I use:

```
mesh(X,Y,Z, color = (1,1,1), opacity=0.5)
```

to color the whole sphere white, and then

```
mesh(X,Y,Z, color = (1,0,1), mask = active_region, opacity=0.5)
```

to color some parts purple, where

```
active_region = [[False False False False False False  True]
                 [False False False False False False  True]
                 [False False False False False  True  True]
                 [False False False  True  True  True  True]
                 [False False  True  True  True  True  True]
                 [False False False  True  True  True  True]
                 [False False False False False False  True]]
```

but this results in a completely purple sphere.  X, Y, and Z are all arrays with shape (7,7), just like active_region.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmm, that should do it. What happens if all the values is True or False?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Masking works based on scalars and not when you have set a solid color.  Try this instead:

```
import numpy as np
m = mesh(X,Y,Z, mask=active_region, opacity=0.5)
m.mlab_source = ones_like(X)
```

The masking works by setting the scalar to Nan where masked.  The geometry drawn is the same but the masked regions are not displayed if the scalars are Nan's.

In any case, here is a complete working example for your reference:

```
import numpy as np
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:100j, 0:2 * np.pi:100j]
x = np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(phi)
mask = np.zeros_like(x).astype(bool)
mask[::5] = True
mask[:,::5] = True

from mayavi import mlab
mlab.mesh(x, y, z, scalars=z, mask=mask)
```

Note that you don't need to provide the scalars, its just that if you provide an explicit color there will be no masking.  Also the scalars here are simply set to `z` you can use any compatible array, even a constant value via  `ones_like(X)`.

Turns out that if you have a constant scalar VTK 5.6 doesn't seem to mask your points correctly, if you have VTK 5.10 you can do the following:

```
m = mlab.mesh(x, y, z, scalars=scalars, mask=mask)
m.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.lut.nan_color = 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Otherwise, use `scalar=z` and setup a constant color lookup table.  You can create your own by clicking on "colors and legends" on the pipeline editor, then click on "launch lut editor".  To use this custom color map, do the following:

```
scalars = np.ones_like(x)
m = mlab.mesh(x, y, z, scalars=scalars, mask=mask)
m.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.lut_mode = 'file'
m.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.file_name = '/path/to/your.lut'
```

If you do not want to mess with the LUT editor and all that malarky, here is a pure numpy version that you can do right from Python.

```
m = mlab.mesh(x, y, z, scalars=z, mask=mask)
# Lets make some colors:
#    this is an array of (R, G, B, A) values (each in range 0-255), there should
#    be at least 2 colors in the array.
colors = np.zeros((2, 4), dtype='uint8')
# Set the green value to constant.
colors[:,1] = 255
# the alpha value to fully opaque.
colors[:,3] = 255
# Now use this colormap.
m.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.lut.table = colors
```

Note that the colors array should have at least 2 colors and can have as many as you like.  For a constant color 2 should suffice.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help, but I'm still having problems.

I tried the updated example and I still do not see any masking.

Can you attach a picture of the output you get?

My version information:

Mayavi version 4.0.0 - VTK version 5.6.0
Python 2.7.2 |EPD 7.1-2 
wxPython 2.8.10.1

I also don't understand what scalars is, can you explain or give me a reference?

Comment: I updated to version 4.3.0 - VTK version 5.6.0  Python 2.7.3 | 64-bit | Qt 1.1.2 and it works!

Thanks!

Comment: I would still very much like to know how the 'scalars' parameter works.

When I try it with ones_like(X), the masking seems to be turned off and the whole sphere turns blue still.

Comment: Yeah I cannot get this to work with mask except using scalars=z, like you have, or scalars = x or y.  So my hypothesis so far is that it must be one of the first three variables, which really doesn't work for what I am trying to do.  I need a way to set the colors myself.

Comment: You are right, there seems to be a VTK bug in this regard so a constant scalar does not seem to work.  If you have VTK-5.10 available then you can work around this but it appears that you do not have that. "scalars" is a scalar attribute associated with each point on your data and the data is displayed as a color by going through the lookup table.  The masking works by turning all "Nan" values into transparent colors and somehow with a constant color, VTK seems to fail to make it transparent.  One option for you would be to create a lut file with a constant color and use that.

Comment: FWIW, I've added a test_mesh_mask_custom_colors example to mlab which illustrates the above and which will hopefully be available in the next mayavi release.